# Flutter: Change default textDirection on the whole app to RTL

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm building an Arabic based app (RTL language) using flutter and I guess there is a way better than using `Directionality` in each page like this `Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: FacultyPage())` as I don't feel it's a clean approach and sometimes I forget to implement `Directionality` as parent widget especially in large apps with a lot of pages/screens.

So the default layout becomes RTL no need to redoing it by `Directionality` each screen/page.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to set `RTL` configuration for the entire app is:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Directionality( // use this
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, // set it to rtl 
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: this is what I'm trying to avoid, as I need to wrap each page with `Directionality` not the whole app

Comment: Your title says something different `Change default text direction on whole app to RTL`.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to set *directionality* across the app without defining `Directionality` widget(s) is to use [localizations delegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/localizationsDelegates.html).

See example below.

**my_localization_delegate.dart**

```
class MyLocalizationDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<WidgetsLocalizations> {

  final MyLocalization mylocalization;

  MyLocalizationDelegate(this.myLocalization);

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => true;

  @override
  Future<WidgetsLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async => mylocalization

  @override
  bool shouldReload(MyLocalizationDelegate old) => false;
}
```

**my_localization.dart**

```
class MyLocalization implements WidgetsLocalizations {
  @override
  TextDirection get textDirection {
     // logic to return the correct directionality
  }
}
```

**your_app.dart**

```
  final MyLocalization _myLocalization = Mylocalization();
  final MyLocalizationDelegate _myLocalizationDelegate = MyLocalizationDelegate(_myLocalization);

  ...

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [_myLocalizationDelegate],

 ...
```

Comment: This idea occurred to me by reading docs. I'm wondering why nobody mentions this like you did. Glad to validate my thoughts with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Localization and Internationalization

When you will specify Arabic locale as explained below in Main MyApp state MaterialApp it will change Directionality of each widget in the subtree of your app.

Explained very well in Flutter documentation [Link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

After Localization and Intl dependencies you can define and set Locale for Arabic like this in you myApp state MaterialApp like this.

I have used findAncestorStateOfType in Parent MyApp to setLocale in Child

Here is the code

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale locale) {
    _MyAppState? state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
    state!.setLocale(locale);
  }

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key)
  late Locale _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale value) {
    setState(() {
      _locale = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate, // Add this line
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
        Locale('ar', ''), // Spanish, no country code
      ],
      locale: _locale,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      // themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      // themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: MyTheme.lightTheme(context),
      darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme(context),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => LoginScreen1(), //LoginPage(),
        MyRoutes.loginRoute: (context) => LoginScreen1(), //LoginPage(),
        MyRoutes.signupRoute: (context) => const SignUpScreen1(),
        MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => HomePage(),
```